# ¿Por qué se usa el subjuntivo en "Que haya huido significa que está mezclada en el asunto"?

Tags: subjuntivo

No entiendo porqué en esta frase se emplea el subjuntivo. ¿Acaso tiene que ver con el orden de las palabras inverso?

> **Que haya huido** significa que está mezclada en el asunto.

Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué frase alternativa te parece más correcta?

Comment: La respuesta es que la subordinada ("que haya huido") actúa como el sujeto de la oracion. Por supuesto, no es tan simple como eso, pero no consigo dar con referencias que expliquen el asunto con más detalle. Esperaba encontrar algo en la sección [43.4](http://aplica.rae.es/grweb/cgi-bin/v.cgi?i=wGzyiLLBNyhlriUw) de la Nueva gramática, pero no se habla del modo en esa sección.

Comment: Para que actúe como sujeto (_sustantivo_), necesita un pronombre (_que_), forzando el subjuntivo. Por eso también puedes ponerle artículo: _el_ que haya huido...

Comment: ¿Puede ser que lo que está omitido es "el hecho de que"?

Comment: Chicos, pues si lo he entendido bien: aquí tenemos una oración principal „Que haya huido significa“ (el sujeto „Que haya huido“ y el predicado „significa“) y una oración completiva „que está mezclada en el asunto“ ¿verdad?

Answer (score 3):

"Que haya huído" en ese caso es subjuntivo porque es una situación hipotética.

Ahora, podría argumentarse que no es hipotética porque ella de hecho en la realidad sí huyó, pero el argumento de la persona que piensa que ella está mezclada en el asunto es un argumento general. Más formalmente:

- En general, las personas que huyen suelen estar involucradas. (1)
- Ella de hecho huyó. (2)
- Por lo tanto ella está involucrada. (3)

La primera premisa puede expresarse también con subjuntivo usando una oración hipotética como sustantivo: "Que alguien huya significa que está involucrado". La oración que provoca tu pregunta es un poco complicada porque en una sola oración mezcla las tres partes del argumento: La hipótesis, la realidad objetiva, y la conclusión probable que se deduce a partir de ellas.

Comment: Para aclarar un poco lo que dices en el segundo párrafo recuerda que 'hipotético' no quiere decir que no haya pasado. 'Hipotético' es [1. adj. Perteneciente o relativo a la hipótesis o que se funda en ella.](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KUukzGX) y no tiene más asepciones. En este caso la parte del subjuntivo es la hipótesis desde la cual se llega a la conclusión.